# XCode 7 crashes when clicking on storyboard and solution by Apple engineers in dev forum does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, storyboard, xcode7-beta2

I got XCode 7 beta 2 installed and I do the following steps:

- create a new XCode project (single view application)
- add a Watch target to the project
- select any **.storyboard** file

There is a [similar discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/3978?answerId=11908022#11908022) on the apple developer forum but the solution suggested by the **Apple engineers** does not work.

Anyone had better luck?

---

This is the Mac OS version and hardware specification I got:

[image]

Comment: are you using alcatraz or any plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Well what I would suggest is updating OS X Yosemite. After you do that close all applications (including safari) except Xcode beta. Once opened try click the app's main file (at top) when on that ctrl click on the storyboard:

> "Open" > "Source Code"

Then simply change one line of code. Then undo it, but **NOT** with command z or going to:

> "Edit" > "Undo"

Just rewrite that line of code. After rewriting that line of code go back to the app's main file. Then ctrl click on the storyboard:

> "Open" > "Interface Builder – Storyboard"

That should work if not please be specific in when it first crashed when you did this. And if there is **anything** at all in the storyboard, please tell me. I hope this worked.

Comment: that last part, ctrl on the storyboard file, does the trick! Thx, have not been layouting for a month and found it crashing xcode. lots of posts about this. Only one with a real work around!

Answer (score 0):

In my case storyboards was causing crashing because it was:

> propertyAccessControl="nonLocalizable"

and should hould be:

> propertyAccessControl="none"

Second line in storyboard.